# Regex pattern construction to avoid selective character based on condition

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have tried the following and the o/p is expected.

```
String valueIn = test-3-4-HH{3-4}-FF{38-99}
String[] valueInSplit = valueIn.split("-");

o/p array = [test, 3, 4, HH{3, 4}, FF{38, 99}]
```

Is it possible in regex to to create a patter which avoids the "-" between "{" and "}" so the expected o/p should be

```
o/p array = [test, 3, 4, HH{3-4}, FF{38-99}]
```

Is there any other way to do it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, with the assumption that there is only 1 level of bracket `{}`, and the brackets are open and closed properly. Use this regex with `split` function:

```
-(?![^{}]*})
```

As String literal:

```
"-(?![^{}]*})"
```

The regex checks that the `-` is currently not inside bracket, by checking whether we can find a closing bracket `}` from the current position of the string, given that the character in between does not have an opening bracket `{` or closing bracket `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a negative lookahead in your split. Basically you check if there is a number and a closing bracket after the seperator `-`.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
-(?!\d+\})
```